# Retrieve entries inside Firebase table

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following items within my Firebase database:

[image]

When my page loads, I'm making a call to this table and trying to retrieve the information as shown here:

```
  getExerciseDesc(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(obs => {
        this.execDbRef2.on('value', snapshot => {
            const exerciseInfo = snapshot.val() as Exercise;
            exerciseInfo.id = snapshot.key;
            obs.next(exerciseInfo);
        },
            err => {
                obs.throw(err)
            });
    });
}
```

I'm casting the value to a custom class called Exercise which looks like the following:

```
export class Exercise {
  constructor(
      public id: string,
      public description: string,
  ) {}
}
```

Within my component I have the following code:

```
 getExec() {

    this.bugService.getExerciseDesc().subscribe(exo => {

        console.log(exo);

    },
        err => {
            console.error("unable to get exercises - ", err);
        });


}
```

However, when exo is logged to the console, I see the following:

[image]

Which is not what I expect, I'm expecting to see an object with description and an Id populated.

I have also tried just logged the `snapshot.val()` and referencing the description field as shown:

```
snapshot.val()['description');
```

yet this yields `undefined`

Could some please shed some light into what I'm doing wrong here?

** Update **

Ok so I managed to get this to work using 'child_added' within my service function, however I feel this is incorrect as I don't want to subscribe to the given table and retrieve new entries every time one has been entered.

Can someone recommend another approach?

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's going on by these disjointed snippets. What path are you actually listening on, `exercise_description/` or `exercise_description/<some id>`? Include a complete, minimal repro rather than random snippets. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note that you're probably listening on the wrong path and you probably want `child_added` instead of `value`

Comment: @Kato this.execDbRef2 points to the exercise table. As mentioned in the update, child_added works however I don't want to subscribe and call the child_added event every time one is added, this table shown holds values that'll be displayed in a dropdown for the user to select. I'm just trying to figure out the best approach for retrieving this sort of information from Firebase